# Using Libclang python bindings, how do you retrieve annotations added to C++ class/struct?

Tags: python, c++, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, libclang

Using the following C++ struct as an example:

```
__attribute__((annotate("MyAttribute")))
struct TestComponent
{
    __attribute__((annotate("MyAttribute")))
    int32_t testInt;
    
    __attribute__((annotate("MyAttribute")))
    bool testBool;

    __attribute__((annotate("MyAttribute")))
    char testChar;
};
```

Given a node (cursor) from clang using (clang module's cindex) while parsing the AST, using the following I can get the annotations on the class members when node is pointing to TestComponent and has a kind equal to CursorKind.STRUCT_DECL:

```
def get_annotations(node):
    annotations = [c.displayname for c in node.get_children()
            if c.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.ANNOTATE_ATTR]
    return annotations
```

But class/struct annotations never show up as children of a struct/class. Is there a way to get to those? Even in the C bindings - I can try Monkeypatching it, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: attribute should be placed between `struct` and `TestComponent`

```cpp
struct __attribute__((annotate("MyAttribute"))) TestComponent
```

If you print `tu.diagnostics`, `clang` does issue a `-Wignored-attributes` warning:

```
test.cpp:2:17: warning: attribute 'annotate' is ignored, place it after "struct" to apply attribute to type declaration [-Wignored-attributes]
```

Once fixed, `ANNOTATE_ATTR` is visible in AST:

```
 test.cpp CursorKind.TRANSLATION_UNIT
   TestComponent CursorKind.STRUCT_DECL
     MyStruct CursorKind.ANNOTATE_ATTR
     testInt CursorKind.FIELD_DECL
       MyInt CursorKind.ANNOTATE_ATTR
     testBool CursorKind.FIELD_DECL
       MyBool CursorKind.ANNOTATE_ATTR
     testChar CursorKind.FIELD_DECL
       MyChar CursorKind.ANNOTATE_ATTR
```

My test code for reference:

```py
code = """
__attribute__((annotate("InvalidAttribute"))) 
struct __attribute__((annotate("MyStruct"))) TestComponent
{
    __attribute__((annotate("MyInt")))
    int testInt;

    __attribute__((annotate("MyBool")))
    bool testBool;

    __attribute__((annotate("MyChar")))
    char testChar;
};
"""

from clang.cindex import Cursor, Index, Config
Config.set_library_file('C:/llvm-16/bin/libclang.dll')

index = Index.create()
args = ['-x', 'c++', '-std=c++20', 'test.cpp']

tu = index.parse(None, args,
                unsaved_files=[('test.cpp', code)])


for d in tu.diagnostics:
    print(d)

def recurse(c: Cursor, indent=0):
    print(' ' * indent, c.spelling, c.kind)
    for n in c.get_children():
        recurse(n, indent + 2)

recurse(tu.cursor)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am far too used to Unreal-style mark-up where you put a struct/class macro before it. All good now.